# Visual Studio Windows forms C# is there a way to make a picture box look at the cursor?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I am doing a project for coursework which is why I am using VS2019 windows forms. I've been trying to get a picture box to look at the cursor and I've not found a solution, This image shows what I want to achieve, the circle with an arrow is the character, the arrow is the direction the character is looking at, and the triangle on the stick is the cursor and the character will always look in the direction of the mouse cursor, so when the mouse cursor moves so does the picture box to look in the cursor's direction. The picture box's only rotates when the mouse cursor moves, it doesn't change it's location but just rotates to look in the direction of the mouse pointer.
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "look at the cursor".  Are you wanting to know the X and Y position of the mouse?  If so, then the position relative to the picture box, the form, the screen, other? Are you wanting to know what control the mouse is hovering over?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Maybe you can draw a diagram to show it, or tell us what your topic is.

Comment: Sorry for making things unclear, I've updated the post and added a diagram to make it a bit more clear about what I want to achieve.

Comment: I think that you may find it easier to move away from forms and look at WPF instead. In any case you need to think about obtaining cursor position, maybe after a mouse button down event (to start obtaining cursor position), and then trigger a rotate of your image.

Comment: I would love to move away from forms but I'm using for my coursework project for A level, I can't move away from it unfortunately, thank you for the advice.

Comment: Your main form has a `MouseMove` event. When you subscribe to it, you'll get the current position of the mouse (as long as it moves within your window). With some simple calculation between the current position and the position of your picture box you should be able to calculate the relative position between both and rotate the image within the picture box accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your problem: C# sets the mouse cursor to a custom image.

Implementation code:

```
    /// <summary>
     /// Set the cursor to the image
     /// </summary>
     private void setBmpCursor()
     {
         //The image needs to be converted to ico format
         //Here can also use the resource file written in the previous article to store pictures
         string path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\source\\repos\\TestRe\\TestRe\\test.ico";
          //original image
          Bitmap cursorBmp = new Bitmap(path);
         //Custom size (double down);
         Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(cursorBmp, cursorBmp.Width / 2, cursorBmp.Height / 2);
         this.Cursor = new Cursor(bmp.GetHicon());
     }
```

achieve effect:

[image]